# How manage time consuming API Calls in NodeJS

Tags: node.js

I am using an API from TinyPng.com which helps in compressing images.

When a user uploads images, I make an API call to TinyPng.com with the URL of the image that I want to compress, it provides a response with a link of the compressed file. Based on image size it could take about a few seconds to get a response.

How can I handle such time consuming processes in NodeJS ?

Comment: What do you mean by "handle"? i.e. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to handle? As long as you are using callbacks, promises, or async await it shouldn't be affecting any other requests coming in. If that process is something you have to do I don't see that it's an actual problem...?

Comment: Promises seems typically a good choice here.

Answer (score 0):

What you should be doing is handling that in the background on the server side. Once the compressed image is ready, download and replace the original one